# create an instance from type with multiple constructor in scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a class I created with 2 constructors.

I want to create an instance of this class using only default constructor.

```
class A (arg1:Int,Arg2:String){
   def this(arg1:Int){
      this(arg1,"hello")
   }
}
```

here is what I tries to do:

```
val tpe = ru.typeOf[A]
val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val clsSym = tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
val clsMirror = mirror.reflectClass(clsSym)
val ctorSym = tpe.decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
val method = clsMirror.reflectConstructor(ctorSym)
val newInstance = method(args:_*)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
constructor ExampleWithCamelCase encapsulates multiple overloaded
alternatives and cannot be treated as a method. Consider invoking 
<offending symbol>.asTerm.alternatives` and manually picking the required method
```

is there away to choose the default constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
classOf[A].getConstructors()(1).newInstance(1)
```

you can simply use the **Java** reflection to `newInstance` to initiate with multiple **constructor**.